# How do I select the best answer?

Tags: support, answers, accepted-answer

How do I select the best answer? I can't seem to find any button.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48246695/4751173) has no answers (it had one, but it has been deleted). You cannot accept the comments under your question, because they're *comments*, not answers.

For more information, see the [FAQ on **How does accepting an answer work?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/295232).

Answer (score 0):

Click the check-mark left of the answer, below the vote icons:

[image]